# Running an iOS SQLite Updates

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm using this to do an Update statement in a test iOS App, the log outputs 'Success' but theres no change in the database. Could anyone point me in the right direction? It'd be greatly appreciated.

I'm brand new to this so please forgive my probably appallingly written code.

```
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"chars.sqlite3"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    const char *sql = "UPDATE characters SET level = 'testing' WHERE id='1'";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, while I don't want to discourage you from adopting defensive programming techniques, your code snippet seems to assume that SQLite throws exceptions when it encounters errors. It will not. Thus, the notion of examining a `sqlite3_errmsg` in the exception handler doesn't quite make sense. Unlike other programming languages, Objective-C try-catch-finally blocks are intended for exceptional situations only, namely unanticipated programmer errors. And if you're doing a lot of exception handling in your code, in general, then you're relying on the wrong techniques for detecting errors.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening the database from the bundle, which is read-only. You should

1. Check for the existence of the database in the Documents folder.
2. If not there, copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder.
3. Now, open the database from the Documents folder.

Comment: Just moved it across and everything's working perfectly. Thanks, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: @user2672330 could you elaborate on what you did?